# Is it leaking inside the wall?

Tags: bathroom, drywall, leak, faucet, bathtub

Any help would be appreciated. When I turn off my bathtub faucet, it leaks from the area around the handle. I have very little plumbing knowledge. However, what are the chances that it is leaking inside the wall? Is it most likely a loose seal of some kind? I just do not want an internal leak of any kind. Btw, the components are very old. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a half-dozen different possible causes of this.  You need to call a plumber or handyman, or find a friend who knows what might be going on.

Comment: we cannot see what you see. A pic or 2 may help us give you some advice.

Comment: Can you get to the area directly underneath?

Comment: Yes, as Aloysius suggests, if there is an access  panel of some sort below or behind the valve you should look there to find out what's going on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to remove the "chrome" part(s) of the faucet to reveal the bronze part. you will then be able to determine the source of the leak and where the water is going.

The exact disassembly instructions vary depending on what you have.